# replace string with map value with if key is match with exact string

Tags: java

```
Map<String, String> hashtable = new Hashtable<>();
hashtable.put("eBook Cover Image", "724242");
hashtable.put("Cover Image", "95757");
hashtable.put("Image", "9242424");
hashtable.put("Composite", "7697979");
hashtable.put("Low-Res PDF (print)", "1111111111111111");
hashtable.put("Cover", "c11111111");

String s = "eBook Cover Image OR (Low-Res PDF (print) AND Composite)";

for (Map.Entry<String, String> m : hashtable.entrySet()) {
    s = s.replace(m.getKey(), m.getValue());
}
```

replacing is not happening properly.

```
eBook c11111111 9242424 OR (1111111111111111 AND pppppppppppppppp)
```

Comment: What result do you expect ? `eBook c11111111 9242424 OR (1111111111111111 AND 7697979)` or maybe `724242  OR (1111111111111111 AND 7697979)` ?

Comment: I ran your code and got: `724242 OR (1111111111111111 AND 7697979)`

Comment: 724242 OR (1111111111111111 AND 7697979)

Comment: A `Hashtable` doesn't maintain the insertion order. if you want to do that, use a `LinkedHashMap` instead.

Comment: when you ran my code,you will get this output like this;eBook c11111111 9242424 OR (1111111111111111 AND 7697979)

Comment: data can be inserted any order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The order in which the entries are iterated is not set with `Hashtable`, so it looks like you're visiting `"Image"` before visiting `"eBook Cover Image"`.

You probably want a [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) where you put the longer keys in the map first (as you have in your example), because it will iterate the entries in *insertion order* (by default).

Comment: insertion can happen in any order in that map.

Comment: @user739115: That would have been important information to put in the question. You'll need to sort the keys by length (longest-first) and loop through them in that order. Nothing in `Hashtable` is going to magically do that for you.